# Apply binding once in knockout component

Tags: d3.js, knockout.js, requirejs

In my web application I have (let's say) 2 tabs, both are custom knockout components. Their visibility is controlled by the following syntax:

```
<div id="page" data-bind="component: { name: currentTab }"></div>
```

where currentTab is an observable with the name of the current tab.

In both tabs I have visualisations with D3.js, using custom bindings. The problem is that these custom bindings are reinitialised after opening a tab. Is there a way to only load them once so that they don't need to be redrawn?

Note that the component's viewmodels aren't reinitialised, as they are created with the { instance: new viewModel() } trick:

```
define(['knockout', 'text!./tab-one.html', 'jquery'], function(ko, template, $) {

    function ViewModel() {
        var self = this;
    };

    return {
        viewModel: { instance: new ViewModel() },
        template: template
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to change slightly your approach:

```
<div id="page">
    <div id="tab-1" data-bind="visible: (currentTab() == 'drawing-1'), component:{name:'drawing-1'}"></div>
    <div id="tab-2" data-bind="visible: (currentTab() == 'drawing-2'), component:{name:'drawing-2'}"></div>
</div>
```

As alternative, you can add some more flexibility to your components if you provide a viewmodel, for example to encapsulate the logic of the visibility inside the component itself, and moreover - if you can also eventually skip the first redraw at component initialization:

This is just an example, but you can see the idea:

```
ko.components.register('drawing', {
    viewModel: function(params) {
        // Behaviors
        this.active1 = params.currentTab == 'drawing-1';
        this.active2 = params.currentTab == 'drawing-2';
        this.draw = ko.computed(function() {
            if (!ko.computedContext.isInitial()) {
                // do some changes to the drawing
            }
        });
    },
    template:
        '<div data-bind="visible: active1">'+
            // drawing 1
        '</div>'+
        '<div data-bind="visible: active2">'+
            // drawing 2
        '</div>'
});
```